# How spells and enchantments are created and used?

Tags: magic

I just found this stackenchange and wanted to share random ideas for a game, so I could get some feedback from your opinions and experiences.

The matter is: How magical spells, enchantments, artifacts or any kind of magical thing, are created?

Right now I'm putting aside the idea of magic being something that comes from faith or any other subjective way. It's a world where magic has a nature. Even if it would be unnatural in our world, magic coexist or is part of the natural forces of this world. So it has rules to follow.

You always hear on many fantasy works things like:

- This spell was crafted by this powerful wizard
- That is an ancient enchantment conceived by this ancient culture

But the process through it was created is never fully clarified. You always see the final product and how to use it.

As a programmer, I can't stop thinking that spells are just like programs, written in some kind of programming language, like runes or any other kind of magical tongue. And a common magician is just a guy that "doble-click" on that program to execute the spell. For example, a magic scroll.

So, there most be a mechanism to formulate spells. You'd need conditionals and other statments for a spell to be constructed. To create a counter spell that activates automatically you have to check your opponent's magic, "if it's fire magic then activate this other spell", right?

I've been thinking about a world where magic could be created, and not just use some precrafted or prefixed magic tricks. But for that, I need the basics. The basic would be the nature of magic itself. Wouldn't care if it's something that works just because. But these are the fundamental elements (the lego blocks) to create more powerful spells.

For example, runes are combined to defined some behavior and create a enchantment for your armor. Each rune has a fundamental force within it or gives some kind of logic, but are useless by itself.

Simples spells like light a candle or complex ones like casting a fireball are fundamentally the same, it's just matter of the complexity of your "magical algorithms" (Think I've heard of "magical matrix" somewhere, funny names though).

To light a candle, you need to accumulate a bit of fire magic and move it to the candle's wick. For a fireball, you need to accumulate more magic, so you need to iterate over that part until you have enough, the move it (or throw without mercy) to your enemy. Move it gently and throw it would be slightly different spells, the latter being more "complex" since you have to accumulate potential energy before throwing it at full speed.

I can't imagine how chaotic would be if random people could create any magic they wish without having to pay a cost. So, of course, every spell needs to be paid somehow. Mana, magic energy, natural energy, your own life, a combination of all of them perhaps? The more complex your spells is, the more you got to paid.

What do you think? I'd love to know if someone has had this idea or anything related to this topic.

PD: English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Our help center, under "what kind of question should I avoid asking?" lists:  1)your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
2) there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” Please rework your question to ask a worldbuilding question according to our standards.

Comment: After you've figured out [how to ask a good question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then reflect that you've exclusively talked about a quantitative algorithmic approach, whereas all the magic systems you'll usually encounter will be biassed heavily towards the qualitative, value-system based approach. If it's purely mechanistic, then it'll be seen as soulless, without human connection. That said, there's plenty of games that work like that.

Comment: Welcome to world building. Just a hint because it's a typical beginner's approach: it seems like you're focusing on fancy words without meaning like fundamental force or nature (and many more phrases like that). The best way to approach a problem is breaking it down into smaller ones, one step at a time. Avoid things without meaning that just sound great to you. World building is not that hard, just start at the beginning. What do you want to accomplish? The less words you need that don't have any meaning without context, the more solid your idea

Comment: Do check out the [tour] and [help] and learn [what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about). This is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A forum that accepts concise & focused queries.